# Retrieve only 1 of a duplicated record Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, controller

I am trying to find out how to only display 1 of  duplicated records in ruby on rails in my view.

In my controller I have

```
previous_three_days = Date.today - 3
@results = Result.where("fixture_date <= ?", previous_three_days)
@result_date = @results.group_by {|r| r.fixture_date}
```

In my view i then have this

```
   <% @result_date.sort.each do |date, results| %>
    <%= date %>

     <% results.each do |result| %>
      <%= result.home_team %>
        <%= result.home_score %> -
        <%= result.away_score %>
      <%= result.away_team %></span>

     <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

So whilst i am grouping by the fixture_date i would like to ensure that the home_team v away_team is unique, using .uniq does not work in this case.

My test data in this case looks like

```
19  Everton West Ham    2   0   2013-05-12  77  2013-05-16 11:18:18 2013-05-16 11:18:18
20  Everton West Ham    2   0   2013-05-12  80  2013-05-16 11:18:18 2013-05-16 11:18:18
21  Fulham  Liverpool   1   3   2013-05-12  78  2013-05-16 11:18:18 2013-05-16 11:18:18
22  Fulham  Liverpool   1   3   2013-05-12  81  2013-05-16 11:18:18 2013-05-16 11:18:18
23  Stoke   Tottenham   1   2   2013-05-12  76  2013-05-16 11:18:18 2013-05-16 11:18:18
24  Stoke   Tottenham   1   2   2013-05-12  79  2013-05-16 11:18:18 2013-05-16 11:18:18
```

and the output in the view is

```
Everton 2 - 0 West Ham
Everton 2 - 0 West Ham
Fulham 1 - 3 Liverpool
Fulham 1 - 3 Liverpool
Stoke 1 - 2 Tottenham
Stoke 1 - 2 Tottenham
```

which makes sense as i am grouping by fixture_date

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@results = Result.where("fixture_date <= ?", previous_three_days).group("home_team, away_team, fixture_date")
```

and then in view

```
<% @results.each do |result| %>
  <%= result.home_team %>
  <%= result.home_score %> -
  <%= result.away_score %>
  <%= result.away_team %></span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks very much, threw me a little as i was grouping the results, so im grouping a group now :)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have duplications in database? Maybe you can fix that?

If not you can use unique

```
results = results.uniq { |r| r.home_team }
```

Grouping posted above is better, because it will be faster and more elegant